# Why PDF is greater than CDF in normal distribution?

Tags: python

In my mind, CDF is the integration of PDF.

```py
from scipy import stats
stats.norm.cdf(-1)

0.15865525393145707
```

```py
stats.norm.pdf(-1)

0.24197072451914337
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, the integral of a function at a point is not necessarily greater than the value of the function. Consider the integral of `y=1-x` for `x>=0`. At `x=0`, the integral is zero but the function is 1.